# C++. Запись атрибутов класса чтением из файла

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Никак не могу понять, как мне осуществить присваивание переменных nm, ag, wg для атрибутов класса, чтобы программа запоминала их в файле и в будущем использовала, каждый раз выводя обновленные данные в "главном меню". Хелп, я совсем еще зеленый

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class human {
public:
    string age, weight, name;
    void print() {
        cout << "\n\tИмя: " << name << "\n\tВозраст: " << age << "\n\tВес: " << weight;
    }
};


int basData () {
    
    human user;
    user.age;
    user.weight;
    user.name;
    
    cout << "\n1. Внесение/изменение личных данных\n" << "2. Змейка\n" << "3. Удаление профиля\n" << "Сделайте выбор: ";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        user.print();
        cout << "\n\n1. Внести изменения" << "\n2. Вернуться на главную страницу" << "\nСделайте выбор: ";
        int choice2;
        cin >> choice2;

        if (choice2 == 1) {
           cout << "Имя: ";
            cin >> user.name;
           cout << "Возраст: ";
            cin >> user.age;
           cout << "Вес: ";
            cin >> user.weight;

            ofstream file;
            file.open(user.name + ".txt");
            file << user.name << endl << user.age << endl << user.weight;
            file.close();

            string nm, ag, wg;

            ifstream read(user.name + ".txt");
            getline(read, nm);
            getline(read, ag);
            getline(read, wg);
            
             nm = user.name;
             ag = user.age;
             wg = user.weight;

            return basData();
        }
        else {
            basData();
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит вот это? ```nm = user.name;
             ag = user.age;
             wg = user.weight;``` Зачем оно? Вы прочитали в эти переменные что-то из файла, и тут же присвоили этим переменным  значения из полей объекта.

Comment: Что должно означать вот это: ```return basData();
        }
        else {
            basData();``` ? Почитайте про вызов функций, рекурсию...

Comment: ну и в целом, обдумайте  логику своего кода. Пока у Вас все в кучу. Что же касается вопроса..... Вы же прочитали из файла то, что записали туда.... Так читайте в те поля объекта, в которых это должно быть.

Comment: это опечатка после переписывания, там по факту читается в поля объекта, но вывод точно такой же, ничего не меняется. Извиняюсь, не заметил! По факту там user,.name = ag и т.д. 
return basData(); }         else {             basData() - это, как я рассчитывал, возврат в функци. т.е. в конце конструкции свич идет возврат и при вводе "2" и других, другими словами вкладки "вернуться", тоже возврат на предыдущую страницу

Comment: Почитайте про рекурсию. Вы на каждом проходе функции снова ее вызываете, и никогда не возвращаете результат. Судя по всему, на данный момент Вы не понимаете, как работает функция, передача аргументов в функцию, возврат результатов. Добрый совет - почитайте немного теорию, разберитесь с этими вопросами, иначе так и будете биться  лбом в стену, и никакие подсказки Вам не помогут, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте конструктор для класса Human

```
Human() : age("test"), weight("test"), name("test") {}
```

Это излишне:

```
user.age;
user.weight;
user.name;
```

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробнее, как передать значения переменных из файла

Comment: Вряд ли это можно считать ответом.